# My directx sound buffer has static noise

Tags: c#, directx, sharpdx, directsound

So I enjoy working on college assignments (to keep some of my skills sharp) and I've decided to tackle this one:

http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/assignments/dsp.html

I'm running MSVS2015 C#/Console app along with the SharpDX package that gives me access to some underlying DirectSound capabilities. I'm just trying to create and play a 2 second note 'A' as they go over in the first example. When I run the following code it plays the 2 seconds but it is very static-y. I'm assuming there is something off with my calculations but I can't figure out what exactly. Does anyone have experience writing their own digital sound buffers?

Thanks,
- Jeff

```
public class Execution : IDisposable
{
    IntPtr Handle;
    DirectSound Device;
    SecondarySoundBuffer Buffer;
 
    public Execution()
    {
        Handle = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;
 
        Device = new DirectSound();
        Device.SetCooperativeLevel(Handle, CooperativeLevel.Priority);
 
        var rate = 44100;
        var bits = 16;
        var channels = 1;
        var waveFormat = new WaveFormat(rate, bits, channels);
 
        // Create a buffer with 2 seconds of sample data
        var seconds = 2;
 
        var bufferDescription = new SoundBufferDescription() { Format = waveFormat, BufferBytes = waveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond * seconds };
        Buffer = new SecondarySoundBuffer(Device, bufferDescription);
 
        var noteFrequency = 440f;       // A
        var bufferData = new float[bufferDescription.BufferBytes];
 
        var count = 0;
        for (var sample = 0; sample < bufferDescription.BufferBytes; sample++)
        {
            var sampleInSeconds = (float)sample / (float)bufferDescription.BufferBytes * (float)seconds;
            var value = (float)Math.Sin(2f * Math.PI * noteFrequency * sampleInSeconds );
            bufferData[sample] = value;
        }
 
        Buffer.Write(bufferData, 0, LockFlags.EntireBuffer);
    }
 
    public void Execute()
    {
        Buffer.Play(0, 0);
    }
 
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Buffer.Dispose();
        Device.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of `var bits = 16;` the expected value should be a short (-32768, +32767), so simply replacing bufferData to a `new short[bufferDescription.BufferBytes];` and the final calculation `bufferData[sample] = (short)(value * short.MaxValue);` should hopefully fix the noise